# How to identify essential tags?

Tags: feature-request, tags

In AE, the most important information one can find in the majority of questions is:

1. Phone manufacturer-model
2. Android version
3. Rooted/not rooted
4. Custom ROM installed (if any)

Thus, being those tags as important as they are, don't you think it's a good idea to provide a special way to identify them?

I've been thinking about this and a couple of ideas come to my mind:

- A **color scheme**, just like the one being used here at Meta
  [image: Tag colors in Meta]
- **Icons** to identify each one the four tag categories mentioned above, like the icons for some tags at StackOverflow (android, facebook, google-maps, etc.)
  [image: Tag icons in StackOverflow]

I think this would help the users to quickly identify the essential tags they should include when asking a question, thus decreasing the amount of comments like *"what brand and model of phone do you have?"*, *"are you rooted?"*, etc; therefore boosting the average quality of the questions in AE.

Is this feature something feasible?

Comment: I agree with Al regarding how we should do tagging.  Regarding having different type of tags, I do like the idea to a degree -- but this is also something SE has repeatedly said will not be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The icons you see besides the tags are "sponsored" tags. People pay so that the icons appear.

The colors provide a meta layer for tags, like "required" or "mod only".

IIRC the order how tags are displayed on questions is "by tag usage count", so important tags are leftmost, sometimes even in the page title. Because of that there is IMHO no need for such feature.

<sup>From recent meta/chat discussions, I think we may have to start a discussion about taging policy. But that should be done in a new meta question.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Heck, no.

Tags should describe the **question**. They shouldn't describe the device or the environment. More often than not, the answer(s) to the question has nothing to do with the model of the device or the OS or whether it's rooted or not. Those things are important bits of information to help make the question clearer, but they shouldn't be tags.